# Sqldeveloper to define variable of RAW type

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using SQL developer (Oracle's SQL developer) and have a table with column of `raw` type. Example values in this column are:

```
ABE478C1388D9015875646AD16010B13
D78ABC797BC898AA9710BC090913B15C
```

I want to use these values inside my `SELECT` statement as variables, which I define beforehand:

```
define carHashId = 'ABE478C1388D9015875646AD16010B13'
```

When I use this variable inside the `WHERE` clause:
`WHERE hid = &&carHashId`
I always get the following error:

```
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 128 bytes was specified,
           or a password identifier longer than 30 bytes was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 128 bytes for identifiers,
           and at most 30 bytes for password identifiers.
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: SQL developer, as in Oracle's SQL developer?

Comment: @jarlh yes, Oracle's SQL developer.

Answer (score 0):

Use HEXTORAW()
select HEXTORAW('ABE478C1388D9015875646AD16010B13') from dual ;

Note that
utl_raw.cast_to_raw('ABE478C1388D9015875646AD16010B13')
will give
'4142453437384331333838443930313538373536343641443136303130423133'
which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a substitution variable, so you need to include quotes when using it:

```
define carHashId = ABE478C1388D9015875646AD16010B13

select '&carHashId' from dual
```

The quotation marks in the `define` statement don't do anything in SQL Developer. You could use any of the following and ge the same result:

```
define carHashId = ABE478C1388D9015875646AD16010B13
```

```
define carHashId = 'ABE478C1388D9015875646AD16010B13'
```

```
define carHashId = "ABE478C1388D9015875646AD16010B13"
```